# One li is not on the same line as the other?

Tags: css, menu, html-lists

I got a problem with my menu. The last `li` element is not on the same line as the others. The last `li` contains a `div`, the other 3 contains anchor tags. 
I mean, it's basically on the same line, but the last looks like it's having a `margin-top: 1px` or something. But it don't have that.

Comment: I could not add an image because i'm new here.

Comment: can u add the code or create fiddle so that we can check it out http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Well... it's not so hard to do it..

Comment: Load image to any image-sharing site and give us link, we will edit the question and add the image.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4enmw.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Without more code this can be difficult, but from the image link you provided here is the code to achieve you required output:

```css
        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }
        /*This is probably what was causing your miss-alignment*/
            ul li {
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid #808080;
                border-radius:5px;
                padding: 10px 50px;
            }
```

```html
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a>a1</a></li>
            <li><a>a2</a></li>
            <li><a>a3</a></li>
            <li><div>div</div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Another possibility is that you are adding margin to all div or same-class elements by mistake.